# Elastic Search 6.4 Index Creation

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I run the ES 6.4 version on my windows machine. The ES in itself runs fine but while creating index it gives me error. The mapping file i used is below :-

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "household_customer": {
      "properties": {
        "phoneNumber": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "comma_analyzer"
        },
        "householdId": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "householdType": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "householdEligible": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "householdName": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "customerId": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "customerType": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "postalCode": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "houseNumber": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "houseNumberAddition": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "kvk": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "iban": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "benefitAssigned": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "benefitName": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "benefitStatus": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "benefitStatusDate": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "hasFixed": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isFixedEligible": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "hasCable": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isCableEligible": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "hasInternet": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isInternetEligible": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "hasDigitalTV": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isDigitalTVEligible": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "eligible": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "householdCustomerKey": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "activeInd": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "blacklistInd": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "blacklistCriteria": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    },
     "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "comma_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "comma_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "comma_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
}
}
}
```

Command used :- http://localhost:9200/household_customer ..... I ran the command via Postman

Error :-

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [analysis : {analyzer={comma_analyzer={tokenizer=comma_tokenizer}}, tokenizer={comma_tokenizer={pattern=,, type=pattern}}}]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [settings]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [analysis : {analyzer={comma_analyzer={tokenizer=comma_tokenizer}}, tokenizer={comma_tokenizer={pattern=,, type=pattern}}}]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [analysis : {analyzer={comma_analyzer={tokenizer=comma_tokenizer}}, tokenizer={comma_tokenizer={pattern=,, type=pattern}}}]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Similar kind of index creation works in ES2.x while it fails for ES 6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things that will need to be updated. As is pointed out already, the `settings` should be on the same level as `mappings`. The type for `string` also changed with newer versions of Elasticsearch. For the not analyzed strings, use `keyword` and for the analyzed strings use `text`.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "household_customer": {
      "properties": {
        "phoneNumber": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "comma_analyzer"
        },
        "householdId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "householdType": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "householdEligible": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "householdName": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "customerId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "customerType": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "postalCode": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "houseNumber": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "houseNumberAddition": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "kvk": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "iban": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "benefitAssigned": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "benefitName": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "benefitStatus": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "benefitStatusDate": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "hasFixed": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isFixedEligible": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "hasCable": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isCableEligible": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "hasInternet": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isInternetEligible": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "hasDigitalTV": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "isDigitalTVEligible": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "eligible": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "householdCustomerKey": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "activeInd": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "blacklistInd": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "blacklistCriteria": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "comma_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "comma_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "comma_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, as the errors you are seeing point out, you need to define the `comma_analyzer` in your `settings`. Probably using a pattern analyzer. Something like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "comma_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ","
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `settings`object is inside `mappings`, but it should be on the same level. Try it like this:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "household_customer": {
            "properties": {
                "phoneNumber": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "analyzed",
                    "analyzer": "comma_analyzer"
                },
                "householdId": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                (i omitted some stuff here...)
                "blacklistCriteria": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "comma_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "comma_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "comma_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern": ","
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you created the index on an old elasticsearch version with exactly what you posted, I strongly believe that it ignored your settings. Because in earlier versions, there were way less checks and you basically could put almost any JSON object. It might even have considered it to be another type, which was possible in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)